# Testing $log.error in provider with Angular and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs

I have a module that sends an error via $log.error(). This is working and I'm trying to finish the tests for it. My problem is that I'm unable to validate that it logs an error during my spec.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fqEFG9Y8zj1hrnbniB50?p=preview)

code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.provider('MordorProvider', function($logProvider, $injector) {
  // we gotta do this cuz we're a provider and don't have access to $log yet
  var $log = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log');

  this.makeMeAnErrorWorthyOfMordor = function () {
    $log.error('You shall not pass!');
  }

  this.$get = function () {
    return this;
  };
});
```

test:

```
describe('Gandalfs last stand', function() {

  var MordorProvider,
      $log;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_MordorProvider_, _$log_) {
    MordorProvider = _MordorProvider_;
    $log = _$log_;
  }));

  it('should shout out!', function() {
    MordorProvider.makeMeAnErrorWorthyOfMordor();
    expect($log.error.logs).toContain('You shall not pass!');
  });
});
```

I understand that my spec is using ngMock so that I have access to $log.error.logs, but if it doesn't have access to the same $log data, I'm confused on how to test this. If you open the console on that plunkr, you can see that the error is being emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.injector` creates a new injector instance and thus, new `$log` service instance. It isn't supposed to be used inside of Angular app in production, there are too few valid use cases for it.

This

```
app.provider('MordorProvider', function($logProvider, $injector) {
  // we gotta do this cuz we're a provider and don't have access to $log yet
  var $log = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log');
  ...
});
```

can't be considered a workaround to use `$log` in provider. There's simple a reason why service instances aren't available for injection in service providers - they just aren't instantiated yet.

In this case `$log` variable refers to `$log` instance which can't be injected anywhere else and can't be tested. This is why the spec fails on `$log.error.logs`.

There's nothing in this service that would require `provider` instead of `factory`. When `$log` is injected and used in normal way, it can be safely tested with

```
beforeEach(module('plunker', {
  $log: {
    error: jasmine.createSpy()
  }
}));

...
expect($log.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('You shall not pass!');
```

Since the usage of `$window` service is the only thing that makes `$log` unsuitable for injection into `config` and `provider`, it can be cloned and modified to evade this limitation:

```
angular.module('uniformLog', []).config(function ($provide, $injector, $logProvider) {
  var uniformLog = $injector.invoke($logProvider.$get, null, { $window: window });
  $provide.constant('uniformLog', uniformLog);
  // or $provide.constant('$log', ...) to override it entirely
});

angular.module('app', ['uniformLog']).config(function ($logProvider, uniformLog) {
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
  uniformLog.debug('...');
});
```

Comment: Yep, I just tested this with a controller and the format is correct. There are other elements to the provider that I've stripped out that require it to be a provider. I'm using this error notification inside of a module just to let the developer know they didn't initialize it correctly. I think I've found one of the few valid use cases in my app...

Comment: The problem here is that this local `$log` abstraction is no different than calling `console.error` directly. It loses the only reason why it is there - the ability to configure it with `$logProvider.debugEnabled`. Unless the errors should be logged from `config` blocks, this hack can be refactored to use DI in conventional way.

Comment: interestingly, this is exactly where we're initializing this provider. I suppose I should just switch to a console.error then. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: $log is quite simple, the only real problem with using $log during config phase is $window. I've updated the answer to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

You should just mock the $log.error function and verify that it was called

```
beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn($log, 'error');
}

it('should shout out!', function() {
    MordorProvider.makeMeAnErrorWorthyOfMordor();
    expect($log.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith('You shall not pass!');
});
```

Comment: Updated my plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/fqEFG9Y8zj1hrnbniB50?p=preview) and this fails as well